# Jquery textFill plugin doesn't work inside table

Tags: jquery, text

I'm trying to use Jquery textFill to resize my text inside table. 
But I cannot seem to make it work. I create my table dynamically

In the first picture text should resize to the edge....

Plugin: https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill
Code:

```
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = "123412412412414214142";

        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.appendChild(p);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.appendChild(row);
        $(table).textfill({innerTag:"p", debug:"test", maxFontPixels: 0});
```

[image]

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AF9ak/

Comment: textfill is not a native function of jQuery, please tell us which plug-in are you using it or post a fiddle example with the files loaded.

Comment: Your fiddle example work's fine to me... (first impression) note that `maxFontPixels:0` is equal to `maxFontPixels:40` so it's not going to get bigger than 40px (according to default in plugin doc)... Well I saw that you open an issue on github on the plugin page, so no one better than the coder could help you on this. Good luck anyway. (btw, I would not recommend work with tables, to many incompatibilities, and more now with last version of FF, or if you need them, use div's inside)